# Color issues when waking up MBA connected to Apple Thunderbolt Display

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display, color

I haven't got the faintest idea what is causing this issue, but hopefully somebody here has experienced it before.

When I haven't used my computer for a while I decide to wake it up from sleep by pressing a random button on my external keyboard. I have it set up so that the MBA itself is closed, i.e. the Thunderbolt Display is the only screen I am using.

The computer always wakes up immediately and most of the times it works just as expected, **but** sometimes the color of the display is shifted to a quite prominent purplish tone. When this happens I open and close the lid of the laptop, which immediately solves the problem, but I'm curious as to why the problem exists in the first place.

It started happening a few weeks ago and I have been using the MBA with the TB display since summer 2012.

[image: An image taken by my phone showing the discoloration.]

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** Just took a screenshot which after opening and closing the lid doesn't show any discoloration, which leads me to believe this is a hardware issue. Added a picture showing how it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to my belief this is most probably a software issue since I cannot reproduce the problem after updating to the most recent version (10.9.2) of OSX.

Comment: Most recent is 10.9.2 in your case?

Comment: That is correct.